# Book recommendations for reviewing probability and statistics for engineering major

Tags: probability, references, engineering-statistics

I'm an Industrial Engineering Major and I'm looking out for book(s) on Probability and Statistics (Combined would be preferred but separate would do as well) which :

- I, as a **self learner**, can work with.
- Is concise but covers : *Statistical methods for data analysis. Descriptive plots and statistics; observational studies and experiments; confidence interval estimation; hypothesis testing; regression and correlation.* in depth. **I have already studied them once, I just need to review them with greater depth.**
- Cater to engineers and not statisticians. I would prefer theory and application rather than theory and rigor.
- Would help me in my goal of studying Stochastic Models/Simulations/Financial Engineering (again, on my own).
- Has an international edition.
- Recommended/Not Required : Gives examples in R.

I've been through [the similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1667/what-books-provide-an-overview-of-engineering-statistics) but 2 answers are ones which recommend a book which the author himself isn't happy with and the accepted answer is a website.

I've looked at Sheldon Ross, DeGroot, Rohatgi and many more but I'm still not sure if any of them give me what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability theory books for self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15692/probability-theory-books-for-self-study)

Comment: Like you, I want to relearn the subject with similar conditions (theory and apps). Sheldon Ross, DeGroot's books are in my list, but I feel, currently, I will go to : Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences by Jay L. Devore as the main textbook. I will read Ross or DeGroot's book whenever I need a better explanation on some topics or whenever they have topics which are not found in Devore's book, like Moment Generating Function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few recommendations that, combined, strike a balance between theory and practice (with lots of R code and example visualizations). Granted, you shall find emphasis on inference and prediction, a must in a IEOR's toolkit:

- [*All of Statistics* by Larry Wasserman](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/all-of-statistics/)
- [*Elements of Statistical Learning* by Hastie et al.](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)
- [*Handbook of Statistical Analyses in R* by Everitt et al.](http://books.google.com/books/about/A_Handbook_of_Statistical_Analyses_Using.html?id=5-XI_e-9LvYC)
- [*R in Action: Data Analysis and Graphics with R* by Kabacoff](http://www.manning.com/kabacoff/)

Comment: Those seem to be really good books but none of them have international editions and I can't afford them otherwise. Can you suggest some more?

Comment: The book by Hastie et al. is offered as a free pdf download at the book's main website. "R in Action" is available at relatively low cost as a pdf download at manning.com. I believe you can also (legally) obtain the other two as pdf's.

Answer (score 0):

The following book might help you

1. Statistical Methods for Engineers
   ISBN: 9780538735186
   It focuses on data collection methods, random and probability models, design of experiments, hypothesis testing and estimation, control charts and statistical process control

2.Statistical Methods for Engineers and Scientists
ISBN:9780367401825
It includes content related to statistical inference - estimation, hypothesis testing, analysis of variance, regression analysis, statistical process control and reliability, experimental design, introduction to SAS.

3. Introduction to statistical methods
   ISBN:9798629947158
   This book deals with the statistical methods such as Probability, Sampling, Correlation, Regression and Hypothesis Testing and non-parametric tests and advanced statistical models.